# How to proper set a limit to process's priority with libc?

Tags: c, process, glibc, nice

I'm using *setrlimit* to put a limit to the niceness of my program when it runs like a proccess, but it's not working.

```
int main()
{
   struct rlimit limit;

   getrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, &limit); 

   limit.rlim_max = 30;
   limit.rlim_cur = 15;

   setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, &limit)

    while(1)
        sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

When the proccess is running, non-root account is unable to set priority minor than 0 and root can exceed those limits.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're on linux, please check if

```
ulimit -e
```

returns `0`. This is set on my machine:

```
$ ulimit -e
...
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
```

this means, non-root users are only allowed to decrease nice value by this limit. you should be able to modify this limit via `/etc/security/limits.conf` if you have root access.

here are some more details: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3910

Comment: You want the `ulimit -e` for the "nice" limit. `ulimit -r`, the real-time priority, is only relevant when running under a realtime scheduler. And ofcourse remember that a lower nice value means a higher priority. To set the nice value, use setpriority() or nice().